# how to add event calendar to my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I am developing a web application and there I want to add a calendar capability of adding activities to certain date and editing.I search a lot and found javaScript code using `fullcalendar.min.js`. Code have shown as below.
In html I add `<div id="calendar"></div>` and script is

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

       editable: false,      

       header: {

         left: 'prev,next today',

         center: ' title',

         right: 'month,basicWeek'

       },

       timeFormat: "",

       events: [

         <w:kb:item:each type="events">

           {

             id: "<w:id />",

             title: $('<textarea/>').html("<w:escape_html><w:name /></w:escape_html>").val(),

             start: "<w:get name="event:start_date" format="%Y-%m-%d" />",

             end: "<w:get name="event:end_date" format="%Y-%m-%d" />",

             url: "<w:path url='/calendar/event' />",

             allDay: false

           }<w:unless_last>, </w:unless_last>

         </w:kb:item:each>

       ]

     });
```

also I add `<script src="${baseURL}/static/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" ></script>` also. But it is not working (even not showing the calendar). Is there a any other way to achieve my task or correct me with my implementation.

Comment: any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: and you included css and code is wrapped in `$(document).ready()`?